# how to insert sharepoint list to Oracle DB using Powershell

Tags: powershell, oracle11g

I would like to retrieve some list items from a sharepoint list and then load it into an Oracle table.Is this feasible using powershell.
    Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks
** What would be the best way to prepare the table in powershell before inserting into Oracle?

Comment: Anyone dine something similar:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this with SharePoint and SQL Server. There's two parts first you'll want to query a SharePoint list as documented in my blog post:

http://sev17.com/2009/02/using-oledb-with-sharepoint-lists/

Second you'll want insert into a table. In SQL Server I would use the SQLBulkCopy class, there's a similar class for Oracle, but its probably just as easy to generate and execute insert statements from the DataTable returned from SharePoint. This piece will require a bit of work. Take a look at $dt variable and generate insert statemens. As an example

$dt | foreach {"INSERT myOracleTable VALUES ('$($*.Field1)','$($*.Field2)');"}

You could generate a file and use SQLPLus to execute the file:

$dt | foreach {"INSERT myOracleTable VALUES ('$($*.Field1)','$($*.Field2)');"} >> ./out.sql

Or, I've got a two-part series for querying Oracle from Powershell here:

http://sev17.com/tag/oracle/

Edit addded example:

```
#Select
$connString = ‘Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes; DATABASE=http://sharepoint.acme.com/IT/DBAdmin/;LIST={a113df9b-e56e-49d2-b786-03d170d18dbc};‘
$spConn = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connString)
$spConn.open()
$qry=‘Select * from list’
$cmd = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($qry,$spConn)
$da = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd)
$dt = new-object System.Data.dataTable
$da.fill($dt) > $null
$dt
```

Comment: Thanks Chad,But when you say datatable returned from sharepoint list can you show me a sample

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Sharepoint web services to retrieve the information, I've described it somewhat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747910/powershell-exception-new-webserviceproxy-soap/6750067#6750067). I don't have much experience in accessing databases from Powershell, but found a nice blog post [here](http://www.powershell.nu/2009/01/26/sql-through-powershell/) that should fit the bill.