# PowerShell: Exception calling "GetListItems" with "7" argument(s)

Tags: powershell, exception, soap, sharepoint, new-webserviceproxy

Attempting to Get List Items from SharePoint using PowerShell.

I used the example from here [Windows PowerShell Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/06/24/using-new-webserviceproxy-to-get-modify-and-add-items-to-a-list-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx), modified it to use with my site. Now I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "GetListItems" with "7" argument(s): "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."
At line:30 char:1
+ $list = $service.GetListItems($listName, "", $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $qu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException
```

Script I am using:

```
# The uri refers to the path of the service description, e.g. the .asmx page            
$uri = "http://SITE/sites/DefaultCollection/Engineering/Subsite%20(UK)/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"             

# Create the service            
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri  -Namespace SpWs  -UseDefaultCredential            

# The name of the list             
$listName = "Test1"             

# Create xml query to retrieve list.             
$xmlDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument            
$query = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")            
$viewFields = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields")            
$queryOptions = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions")            
$query.set_InnerXml("FieldRef Name='Text1'")             
$rowLimit = "10"            

$list = $null             
$service = $null              

try
    {            
    $service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri  -Namespace SpWs  -UseDefaultCredential
    }            
catch
    {             
    Write-Error $_ -ErrorAction:'SilentlyContinue'             
    }

$list = $service.GetListItems($listName, "", $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, "")

if($service -ne $null)
    {            
    try
        {                    
        $list = $service.GetListItems($listName, "", $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, "")
        }            
    catch
        {             
        Write-Error $_ -ErrorAction:'SilentlyContinue'            
        }            
}
```

Anyone tried this before? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Catch your exception and see what additional details it give. Inside your catch {} add [System.Exception], and then echo it out with ($_.Exception).Message

Comment: The exception being thrown is that shown above ... Exception calling "GetListItems" with "7" argument(s): "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution worked for me..

Add "?WSDL" to the end of $uri string

```
$uri = "http://SITE/sites/DefaultCollection/Engineering/Subsite%20(UK)/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL"
```

According to [this link](http://ss64.com/ps/new-webserviceproxy.html):To return a service description of a Web service that was created by using ASP.NET, append "?WSDL" to the URL of the Web service (for example,  http://www.ss64.com/MyWebService.asmx?WSDL)

Answer (score 0):

The line it is throwing the error at is:

```
$list = $service.GetListItems($listName, "", $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, "")
```

That line is not caught, but here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747910/powershell-exception-new-webserviceproxy-soap) throwing the same error. If you want to try and get a better exception, wrap the line in another try catch:

```
try{
$list = $service.GetListItems($listName, "", $query, $viewFields, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, "")
}
catch{
[System.Exception]
write-host ($_.Exception).Message
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure to add "?WSDL" to your URI which is why the code breaks. Pretends like it doesn't know the definition of the function (atleast I guess)...

Like the one below. I was surprised to see this made my code work. Weird..

$uri = "http://<>/sites/DefaultCollection/Engineering/Subsite%20(UK)/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL"